# Output jQuery AJAX response via PHP script intermediary

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following script that successfully completes an AJAX request:

```
var input = $("#input").val();
$(".pure-button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: input
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#output").val(data);
    });
});
```

`input` contains a string:

```
grant_type=refresh_token&amp;client_id=abcd-efgh&amp;client_secret=ijkl-mnop&amp;refresh_token=qrst-uvwx
```

However, the `.done()` does not seem to be working. Running the AJAX request in the Chrome Extension [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) gives me the following output:

```
{"access_token":"123-456-789",
"token_type":"bearer",
"refresh_token":"987-654-321",
"expires_in":14399}
```

But how do I get this to display in `#output`? It's a blank input field.

**EDIT:**

I thought it might be worth nothing that `script.php` contains the following code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/xml");
echo file_get_contents("https://api.example.com");
?>
```

If the `echo file_get_contents()` is having any bearing on what is returned? Is my initial input string in an XML format? Is the POSTed data even reaching the other server?

**2nd EDIT:**

Changing my `.done()` to `alert(output);` gives me a pop-up containing nothing but `null`. Seems like my PHP script (an apparent hacky way of getting around the Cross-Origin problem) isn't returning the request in a way that I can use.

```
var input = $("#input").val();
$(".pure-button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: input
    }).done(function(output) {
        alert(output); // returns "null"
    });
});
```

Comment: use a div tag instead of input field and use $("#output").html(data);

Comment: is it possible for you to set breakpoint on done function and check data object? e.g. somethimes the data from .net services are stored in data.d property

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a success function in when creating the call, as below:

```
var input = $("#input").val();
$(".pure-button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: input,
        success: function (data) {
          $("#output").val(data);
    });
});
```

See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data ...try using ... `data:{input_data:input}` and use the .html instead of val() ...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: {input_data:input},
    success: function (data) {
      $("#output").html(data);  // to display as text... "output" could be a div element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the content-type of your response to `application/json` in the script.php file?

See this: [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

Comment: Having done this, I now do not get an `alert()` at all. The POST still goes through okay.